# org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'console' not found

Tags: java, xml, spring, struts2, tiles

I don't understand what's wrong with my code since the other tiles are working fine, so I guess it's a mapping problem but I can't find the origin of it.

**console :**

```
2015-02-26 14:41:32,200 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport - Error executing tag: Attribute 'console' not found.
org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'console' not found.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:112)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.HelloWorld_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(HelloWorld_jsp.java:142)
    at org.apache.jsp.HelloWorld_jsp._jspService(HelloWorld_jsp.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2015-02-26 14:41:32,200 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport - Error during rendering
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error executing tag: Attribute 'console' not found.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.HelloWorld_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(HelloWorld_jsp.java:142)
    at org.apache.jsp.HelloWorld_jsp._jspService(HelloWorld_jsp.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: Attribute 'console' not found.
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:112)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    ... 32 more
```

**tiles.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

   <definition name="accueil" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Accueil"/>
      <put-attribute name="header"  value="/tiles/header.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="console"  value="/test1.jsp" />
      <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
   </definition>

   <definition name="/logged" extends="accueil">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Bienvenue"/>
      <put-attribute name="console"  value="/test1.jsp" />
      <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
   </definition>

   <definition name="/notLogged.tiles" extends="accueil">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Bienvenue"/>

      <put-attribute name="body" value="/context/errorLog.jsp"/>
   </definition>


   <definition name="/error.tiles" extends="accueil">

      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Erreur"/>
      <put-attribute name="body" value="/context/error.jsp"/>
   </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**web.xml :**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Projet DAR</display-name>

<!--   <context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value> 
        </context-param> <filter> <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name> <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class> 
        <init-param> <param-name>encoding</param-name> <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 
        </init-param> <init-param> <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name> <param-value>true</param-value> 
        </init-param> </filter>-->

    <context-param> 
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>
          org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
       </param-name>
       <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/tiles.xml
       </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <!-- <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class> -->
        <filter-class> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> -->


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

     <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
      </listener>

      <!-- <listener> 
        <listener-class> fr.altares.jupiter.intuizhtml.web.listener.ApplicationInitListener</listener-class> 
      </listener> -->

      <listener>
           <listener-class>
              org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
           </listener-class>
      </listener> 

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>baseLayout.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>500</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!-- <error-page> <error-code>404</error-code> <location>/context/error404.jsp</location> 
        </error-page> -->

</web-app>
```

**struts.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />


<package name="main"  namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

      <action name="Accueil">
            <result>/baseLayout.jsp</result>

      </action>

        <action name="Accueil" class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport">
             <result name="success" type="tiles">accueil</result>
        </action>

    <action name="Login" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">HelloWorld.jsp</result>
            <result name="notLogged" type="redirectAction">context/errorLog.jsp</result>
        </action>






   </package>
</struts>
```

I constantly get this error on this tile while other are loaded perfectly fine, so I just don't understand

Comment: /test1.jsp shouldn't be /tiles/test1.jsp ?

Comment: I resolved it ! 
That might have contributed but in fact I was pointing to the wrong file !

I post the answer in another post below !

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is pretty dumb but the mapping was wrong.

---

**struts.xml**

```
 <action name="Login" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">HelloWorld.jsp</result>
            <result name="notLogged" type="redirectAction">context/errorLog.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

becomes

```
 <action name="Login" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/logged.tiles</result>
            <result name="notLogged" type="tiles">/notLogged.tiles</result>
        </action>
```

---

**tiles.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>

   <definition name="accueil" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Accueil"/>
      <put-attribute name="header"  value="/tiles/header.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="console"  value="/test1.jsp" />
      <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
   </definition>

   <definition name="/logged" extends="accueil">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Bienvenue"/>
      <put-attribute name="console"  value="/test1.jsp" />
      <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
   </definition>

   <definition name="/notLogged.tiles" extends="accueil">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Bienvenue"/>

      <put-attribute name="body" value="/context/errorLog.jsp"/>
   </definition>
```

becomes

```
<tiles-definitions>

   <definition name="accueil" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Accueil"/>
      <put-attribute name="header"  value="/tiles/header.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="console"  value="/tiles/console.jsp" />
   </definition>

     <definition name="/logged.tiles" extends="accueil">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Bienvenue"/>
      <put-attribute name="console"  value="/tiles/console.jsp" />
      <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
   </definition>

   <definition name="/notLogged.tiles" extends="accueil">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Bienvenue"/>
      <put-attribute name="body" value="/context/errorLog.jsp"/>
   </definition>
```

**And that works fine now !**